# How to access the internet?

Tags: internet

Loki 0.4 recognizes the wireless internet access point, but will not allow access to internet, either through the browser or file up dates. My equipment is an HP Dv6 laptop, with 8 GB RAM. Loki installs perfectly, recognizes my wi-fi router, but no access. I've tried using ethernet wire, but, still no access.

Comment: Add more details to the problem? What do you mean by no access?

Comment: Are you connected to the local network?

Answer (score -1):

Try `sudo service network-manager restart` from command line (cli)

Comment: This might be the solution if the network "goes away" after a while, however not likely if it is not working at all…

Comment: ok then try this `sudo nmcli radio wifi on`